# How can I preview image data urls in linux (e.g. data:image/png;base64, <data>)?

Tags: shell-script, images, feh, image-viewer

I opened some json-based configuration file and I see that there is a `favicon` key whose value is a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs#datatextplainbase64sgvsbg8sifdvcmxkiq) representing a `png`:

```
"favicon": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...
```

I am looking for a way to preview this data url using command-line, e.g. by opening in [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/)

Is there an image viewer that supports this out of the box? Otherwise how should I pre-process image urls so that I can preview the corresponding images?

Ideally I want to have a command `preview-image-url` to which I can pass an image urls via stdin or at least as a file argument.

Comment: Is opening the URL in a browser an option?

Comment: @muru Ideally no. However it does not seem a bad idea in case there are no alternatives. I guess it would be something like  `echo "$imgDataUrl" | chromium "$(cat)"` correct?

Answer (score 1):

```bash
cat | sed 's/.*,//' | base64 --decode | feh -
```

Paste data into the terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> twice.

Comment: Nice solution!! Just a note for `Ctl-D`: `base64: invalid input libpng error: Read Error` when using on https://justpaste.it/a94w3. But when I do in the same image url like: `echo "imgUrlData" | sed 's/.*,//' | base64 --decode | feh -` it works. For a smaller image data url though it worked with `Ctl-D`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov) answer I provide an answer to the below question part:

> I opened some **json-based configuration file** and I see that there is a **favicon key whose value is a data url** representing a png [..] looking for a way to preview this data url using command-line, e.g. by opening in feh

```
cat config.json | jq -j '.servers[0].favicon' | sed 's/.*,//' | base64 --decode | feh -
```

The above command will open the image data url stored as a json value, into `feh`.

Comment: If you're using `jq`, then you can do `jq -r '.servers[0].favicon | sub("^.*,"; "")'` and skip the `sed`. `jq` can also do `base64`-decoding, but sadly it expects the decoded output to be valid UTF-8, so `base64 -d` is still needed.